# How to Re-calibrating Device Touch?

Tags: touchscreen, calibration, touch

My Android Phone Fell from my Hand and it's screen is partially Broken. Don't have much of a difference after breaking the screen but I need to Re-Calibrate my Android Device's Display. Is there any way I can do that? With or without Root? I prefer Without Root.